# Data Access Layer Populate Combobox With Parameters

Tags: vb.net, combobox, parameter-passing, data-access-layer

I am using VB.Net (Visual Studio 2013) and N-tier architecture to populate a combo box list. My code for the class is as below

```
    Public Shared Function List() As List(Of AppName.BusinessLogic.BLL_RMCodeComboClass)
    Dim dbo_RMCodeList As New List(Of AppName.BusinessLogic.BLL_RMCodeComboClass)
    Dim connTemp As SqlConnection = AppClass.GetConnection
    Dim strSelectSQL As String = "SELECT [RMCode] FROM [dbo].[RMMaster] WHERE [dbo].[RMMaster].[Category] = '" & strRMType & "'"
    Dim strCommandSelect As New SqlCommand(strSelectSQL, connTemp)
    Try
        connTemp.Open()
        Dim rdrTemp As SqlDataReader = strCommandSelect.ExecuteReader()
        Dim clsdbo_RMCodeList As AppName.BusinessLogic.BLL_RMCodeComboClass
        Do While rdrTemp.Read
            clsdbo_RMCodeList = New BusinessLogic.BLL_RMCodeComboClass
            clsdbo_RMCodeList.RMCode = System.Convert.ToString(rdrTemp("RMCode").ToString)
            dbo_RMCodeList.Add(clsdbo_RMCodeList)
        Loop
        rdrTemp.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connTemp.Close()
    End Try
    Return dbo_RMCodeList
End Function
```

My objective is to retrieve or populate the combobox with RMCodes depending upon the type. Hence I have used the strSelectSQL accordingly. Please help me to pass the value of the Category to this function so that it becomes dynamic. The value of the Type is selected from another combo box on the presentation/UI layer and as such the Code field should be populated according to the Category chosen.

Thanks in advance
CL

Comment: Besides the answer to your question, there are a number of changes you should make to your code to make it better. Firstly, it's very bad that your data access layer has a dependency on your business logic layer. It should only ever be the other way around. The objects that the DAL creates and passes to the BLL should either be defined in the DAL or in a separate project that both the BLL and DAL reference. The DAL should not even know that the BLL exists.

Comment: Secondly, having `Throw ex` in a `Catch` block is bad. If you want to rethrow the same exception then you should just use `Throw`. That will rethrow the exception in its original state while what you're doing will truncate the stack trace to make it look like the exception originated in your method. That said, your `Catch` block is completely pointless. You only have to provide one of the `Catch` and `Finally` blocks and you already have a `Finally` so just omit the `Catch`.

Comment: Thirdly, if you aren't actually doing anything in the `Catch` block and your `Finally` block does nothing but dispose objects then you don't need any of it. Use the `Using` statement to create objects that can be disposed and they will be automatically at the `End Using` statement, whether an exception is thrown or not.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late response, jmcilhinneyThe tip helped me a lot. Its my first attempt at N-tier. I have followed the referencing/dependecy from browsing the web only. Does it make any difference on how the project will be deployed? This project will be deployed on the client machines and a server. Do suggest or point me to a more specific link, where I can get some more help.

Thanks and sorry once again. CL

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
Private Function List(type As String) As List(Of Thing)
    '...

    Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE @Type IS NULL OR Type = @Type")

    command.Parameters.Add("@Type",
                           SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                           50).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(type),
                                          CObj(DBNull.Value),
                                          type)

    '...
End Function
```

That makes the filter optional.  If you pass in `Nothing` or an empty `String` then the SQL parameter is `NULL` and every record matches, otherwise the result set is filtered by the value you pass in.